# Change stroke color of svg icons on different background

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, svg

I Want to change my svg icon into different colors depending on their background
I am using this star icon that has this code:

```
<svg width="33" height="33" viewBox="0 0 33 33" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M16.5344 5.82104L19.7321 12.087L26.6796 13.1919L21.7084 18.1694L22.8045 25.1183L16.5344 21.9286L10.2644 25.1183L11.3604 18.1694L6.38928 13.1919L13.3367 12.087L16.5344 5.82104Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
```

when it has white background it looks like this and have black stoke and that is fine as below image:

[image]

And when I add the same star svg icon to the button component then it should have white stroke and not black stroke, have tried with

```
 svg { fill: currentColor) // then it's invisible on white background, because of its whiteness.
```

like below,
How can I achieve the white star without black stoke ?

[image]

instead of having the star with black stokes
[image]

After following the suggestion where I was sending this two props: scgStroke and svgFill, now in my white background I am getting star with black fill and
in button as below:
[image]
[image]

I want the outside stroke to show not the white fill (fill = "white")
something like below image:
[image]

Comment: probably best and simplest just to have more than one icon.

Comment: No I am not suppose to do so as I am using storybook and its should be selectable from the list when adding on the button

Comment: See this implementation example: https://codesandbox.io/s/svg-current-color-qmtwt6

Comment: Note your icons don't use `fill` at all. They use `stroke`. So that's what you need to set to `currentColor`. At which point, all you need to do is change the CSS color of the parent and the `<svg>` will comply.

Answer (score 0):

You can create component and pass props with colors:

```js
Vue.component('icon', {
  template: `
  <svg width="33" height="33" viewBox="0 0 33 33"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
    <path fill="none" d="M16.4206 26.7218H5.75391V12.722L16.4206 4.39893L27.0872 12.722V26.7218H16.4206ZM16.4206 26.7218V18.7218" :stroke="svgStroke" :stroke-width="strokeWidth"/>
  </svg>`,
  props: {
    svgStroke: {default: 'black'},
    strokeWidth: {default: 2}
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
})
```

```css
.btn {
  background-color: #2f76fd;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: none;
  padding: .5em 1em;
}
.btn-text {
  margin-right: .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <icon></icon>
  <button class="btn">
    <span class="btn-text">Primary</span>
    <icon svg-stroke="white" stroke-width="2"></icon>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but for me the star on the white background is filled with black color . On the button the star works properly but now I need to change the fill=#white " to the above image like the stoke should be white but not the fill, Please see my updates I did above. thanks !

Comment: If I understood you correctly, set `fill=none` and remove `svgFill` prop. So for white background you don't send prop (default is black) and for dark you send `svgStroke` prop. If that is not correct please post images what you want on white/dark background.

Comment: I tried with fill="currentColor" and also with Stoke,

Comment: Hi @Nikola, i did try to implement the above solution in my seperately ( test project ) and it works , but still not working on my main project unfortunately :)